# How to get integratorTxID in stamps.com?

Tags: php, api

I've searched all over the documentation on how to find integratortxid, but found nowhere. I think the documentation lacks it. I would really appreciate if anybody could answer me how to find the integratorTxID for stamps.com since it is required for label printing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integratorTxID is a unique number you generate on your end... I just started working with the stamps api so I could wrong, but that's what I did and it worked for me.

Comment: Yes that true, I had asked to stamps.com personel which advised me to use any unique id like Guid(). I have recently compelted the integration process.. :) thx for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I have also contacted stamps.com support, and they send me a me a new User Guide (which is not on their developers page), where I found the following:

> Fault-Tolerance: The CreateIndicium method can be called multiple times with the same 
>   IntegratorTxID. If the initial call to CreateIndicium fails due to network or other errors, the call may 
>   be repeated to CreateIndicium with the same IntegratorTxID. The risk of double-billing for 
>   postage is eliminated by the integrator building a rollback / retry process.

[image]